# panelMenu of Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a code which includes a

```
  <p:panelMenu></>
```

is it supported only by primefaces3.4? I have used it using Primefaces 3.2 and 3.3.1 also but it was generating an error regarding that particular tag.
After using 3.4 it is generating a different error as "Unresolved compilation problems:the import oracle cannot be resolved OracleDataSource cannot be resolved to a type".. But my code was working fine before including that tag. Is it really a database related problem or panelMenu has any issue? Plz help. 
Thanx in advnce.

Comment: can you post your p:panelMenu part of your xhtml ?? ..